# Why do we (3 dimensional creatures) see in 2 spatial dimensions?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, biophysics, perception, vision

Why do us humans, as 3-dimensional (in terms of space) creatures, see everything in 2 dimensions? Is it because the surface of every 3-dimensional object is 2 dimensional? Or because light enters our eyes through a two dimensional surface? Or another reason altogether!?

Comment: We have stereoscopic vision with our two eyes.

Comment: binocular vision allows you to peek into 3rd dimension as well

Comment: I see everything in 3 dimensions, you might want to consult an optician... Are you perhaps asking why we can't see objects from every angle simultaneously?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about biology/perception and not physics.

Comment: it is about nothing, IMHO

Comment: I think the question might be asking why we can't see objects from all sides, i.e. because our retinas don't cover 4$\pi$ steradians of solid angle.

Comment: @tpg2114 I was not aware that this is just about biology/perception.

Comment: @tpg2114 was of the impression this is a perfectly valid thing to ask from a physics point of view; it isn't asking (explicitly) how do the eyes work to capture light into biological / neurological signals so much as what (physics) principle do they work on that results with 2D vision with depth perception _despite_ a 3D world.

Comment: It's simple doerdimechanics.

Answer (score 6):

It's because our eyes have a 2D array of photo-sensitive receptors. Using two eyes you can 'detect' the third (depth) component.

If you consider each eye to be a single point (for simplicity), the distance between the eyes themselves is a given 'constant'. A distant object in your vision, seen by both eyes, will be in a different position for each eye. You can use the position-angle of the object as it appears in each eye with the known distance between the eyes to calculate the distance to the object.

Comment: This is only true for a certain distance--which isn't very large.  Your brain primarily decides distances through perspective--which it can do just fine with a single eye.  If you don't believe me, then close one eye and tell me that the trees off in the distance don't still appear to be further away.

Comment: While that is true, it also describes a projection of the 3D world onto a 2D surface so information about scale can't be recovered. That is, a small tree nearby, and a large tree far away, would look the same without a parallax effect to distinguish them.

Comment: I've actually been thinking about adding another answer to this problem.  Parallax isn't the full answer (I don't think my answer is correct either).  I'm not totally sure what the proper answer is.  When you look at an object _both_ eyes focus on the object at (slightly) different angles depending on the angle of your "head turn" _and_, in general, when tracking an object, your head turns as the object moves.  I find it difficult to believe that your brain can detect the tiny angular difference, deviating from "head on", of your eyeballs relative to the eye sockets when an object is far away.

Comment: Well... I don't think it's relative to the eye sockets, it should be relative to the other eye. When the eyes are centered on one object, the left eye will see farther objects slightly to the left and nearer objects slightly to the right (if compared to what the right eye sees, and vice versa). Then the angle doesn't matter so much as left-right ordering for each eye and/or focus. At least that much would allow you to mentally (or perhaps the brain, neurologically, but out of scope of this) arrange objects in a line in front of you in order of distance.

Comment: You're talking about peripheral vision.  Then we have to talk about the [fovea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fovea_centralis) and how far away is this relevant.  I disagree with the commenter on my answer about the resolution of the human eye.  But pure resolution isn't important because the angular resolution of the eye deals with _one eye_--not both.  What matters is, given two images, can the brain distinguish a difference?  I still hold that stereoscopic vision is far more important when an object is moving--but that requires understanding "head turn" along with the angles of the two eyes.

Comment: "given two images, can the brain distinguish a difference" I'm of the impression that it can. I've created stereoscopic image generators before, and spent some time working with left and right source images separately; from my experience even a "low res" camera can pick up the differences in the shift / spacing of objects far away, so surely an eye can and the brain then is able to compare it...

Comment: Then you've done experiments.  There must be a limit, yes?  How far away can we expect to detect such differences?  I'm honestly curious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23794/discussion-between-xeren-narcy-and-jared).

Comment: @Jared: But if you look into shrubbery, never mind if nearby or far, with only one eye, it becomes a flat chaos. The trees you still deem distant with only one eye is rather a result of experience. Would you suddenly awake in a country were all trees are double the size, you would judge them nearer.

Answer (score 1):

Having binocular vision *does not* give us "pure depth perception".  When you look at a stationary scene closing one eye will give you the same picture as having both eyes open--you will perceive every object at the same distance as it was perceived with both eyes open.  This is because you are perceiving distance based on perspective--that is the sizes you expect each object to appear.  When you see something you know to be a large object appear small, it appears to be far away.  There are tons of optical illusions which rely on this principle, here's an example (try with one eye open or both--you'll still perceive depth):

[image]

So even though each figure is the same size, we perceive the one (that appears to be) further away as larger (because it appears to be off in the distance, but is the same absolute size, thus we perceive the further away figure to be larger).

Binocular vision helps when an object is *moving*.  It allows you to infer the true 3D coordinate through parallax.  The experiment everyone recommends is trying to catch a ball with one eye closed--it's difficult (although not impossible).  This is where our binocular vision comes in very handy.  Here is an illustration:

[image]

Notice that if one eye is closed it appears the ball goes to the left or right (depending on which eye remains open).  With both eyes open, you can use parallax to infer how much closer the ball has come to you *and* that it is moving to the right.

And it's worth noting that I highly doubt this parallax calculation is innate (if it were then toddlers could catch balls thrown at them, but they can't).  Instead it's always an approximation based on experience.  But the bottom line is that having two sets of eyes (binocular vision), the brain has the data available to make such "calculations" (really they are perceptions).

**Let's Look at Some Math:**

OK, let's add some math to this.  My claim isn't so much that parallax alone cannot determine distance, it's that it's less important than perspective and parallax becomes more important when objects are in motion coming *towards* you.  Let's ask the question, given a certain distance of an object, how far away do *other* objects have to be for us to be able to detect a difference in distance.

[image]

Let's say that the eyes are about 5 cm apart ($\Delta x = 2.5$ cm).  Further let's assume that the retina is about 1 cm behind the lens of the eye ($\Delta h = 1$ cm).  This gives that:

$$
d = \frac{2.5 \text{ cm}^2}{\Delta r}
$$

If we assume that the retina can only resolve up to 1 mm (0.1 cm) then the distances we can resolve through parallax alone is up to 25 cm.  If we assume the retina can resolve up to the size of a cell, .01 mm (the smallest size of a [eukarayotic animal cell](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cell_Biology/Introduction/Cell_size)), then we get a distance 2500 cm, so about 25 meters (a little more than 25 yards)--not very much.  Now granted, if we don't look at it head on, we can probably increase that depth perception, but only slightly.  Further I seriously doubt that the brain can distinguish retinal information on that scale (probably the 1mm to 0.1 mm scale is far more reasonable).  This explains why looking at a stationary object with one eye or both, you pretty well perceive the same distances (because your brain is using perspective--*not* parallax).

An object in motion is different though.  A far away object moving towards you, just as expected doesn't appear to move (e.g. the moon or sun doesn't appear to move because it's far too far away).  However, as the object gets closer, parallax now can become important--regardless of perspective (i.e. how big you think the object should be).

This is a two-fold calculation (which your brain seamlessly computes--well unless you never learned to catch a ball).  On the one hand your brain perceives the ball getting closer because now you aren't detecting absolute distances, you're detecting motion (the distances are changing)!  Further your brain is perceiving how fast the ball is moving towards you because it's seeing the motion plus the fact that the motion is changing with your perceived time.  This gives you some expectation about when the ball will arrive at your hand.

But to make it clear about motion.  When someone throws you a ball, you likely *do not* use parallax initially.  Initially you are using your experience of how a ball flies to do a coarse approximation of where the ball will end up.  It's the last few tenths of a second when the ball is within your stereoscopic sensitive region that you start to use parallax to fine tune where you think the ball is going.  Maybe you've heard the term "watch the ball into your glove" or "watch the ball hit the bat"--these are what you do in those precious few fractions of a second that you *can* use your stereoscopic vision to determine distances through parallax (which I would argue happen within meter/s of your vision).  This is the only distance where stereoscopic vision has an affect.

Comment: Parallax requires movement only if you have a single detector (as in stellar parallax). If you have two (or more) separated detectors, parallax functions against stationary objects when you use both eyes at once. There's an overlook on the New River Gorge in West Virginia where the distance limit for binocular depth perception is between the distance to the river and the distance to the far side of the gorge; the trees near the river stand in front of each other, in 3D, but there's a line partway up the gorge where the trees start to look flat, like a photograph.

Comment: @rob I edited my answer to include a little more mathematical basis for my answer.  I don't believe that parallax explains our depth perception (in terms of stationary pictures)--in that case, I believe it's perspective and I don't think you'll perceive much difference between having both eyes open vs. one eye.

Comment: The human eye has an angular resolution of one arcsecond $\approx 0.3\,\rm mrad$. Even if your displacement model made sense for an optical system with a lens, you've underestimated the position sensitivity of the retina by a factor of 1000.

Comment: @rob Well, I gave several different possible estimates, if I still assume the retina is 1 cm behind the lens, with an angular resolution of 0.0003 radians then you get a $\Delta r$ of about 3 $\mu m$, which (using my numbers) gives a distance of about 80 meters (about 1/3 of 250 m which would have been the case if $\Delta r = 1\ \mu m$).  It's worth mentioning that these numbers represent a physical limit on the eyes.  What's actually important is how large these values need to be for your brain to perceive a difference between the two images--which would require experimentation to determine.

Comment: You're getting closer. [The overlook I mentioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_River_Gorge_Bridge) is a kilometer across, so my binocular vision functions out to 600—800 m.